# Cliente Servidor Java Aplicação fica em loop

Tags: java, cliente-servidor, buffer, byte

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema para escola de reforço
funções simples. No momento em que fui implementar minha classe que
faz a criptografia dos dados precisei mudar também o tipo de dado que
vai trafegar entre cliente e servidor de String para Byte. Já testei
a classe de criptografia e esta 100% funcionando.

Meu problema está com o byte, quando executo o cliente a tela
funciona normal até eu enviar algum dado pra o servidor, ela para de
funcionar e fica estática e não apresenta erro nenhum nem no cliente
e também no servidor, acho que pode ser loop infinito por conta do
byte mas não sei reconhecer.

**classe que uso no cliente e no servidor:**

```
public class Comunicador extends Thread {
    private String ip;
    private int port;
    private Socket sket;
    private BufferedOutputStream out;
    private BufferedInputStream in ;
    public boolean escutando = false;
    public String msg;

    public void setescutando(boolean escutando) {
        this.escutando = escutando;
    }

    public Comunicador(Socket sket) {
        this.sket = sket;
    }

    public Comunicador(String ip, int port) {
        this.ip = ip;
        this.port = port;

        this.conectar();
    }

    public void conectar() {
        try {
            this.sket = new Socket(this.ip, this.port);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Comunicador(int port) {
        this.port = port;

        this.iniciarServidor();
    }

    public void iniciarServidor() {
        try {
            ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(this.port);
            this.sket = server.accept();
            server.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {}
    }

    public void falar(String msg) throws Exception {
        criptografia cript = new criptografia();
        try {
            this.out = new BufferedOutputStream(this.sket.getOutputStream());
            out.write(cript.criptografa(msg));
            //out.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {}
    }

    public String escutar() throws Exception {
        criptografia cript = new criptografia();
        try {
            //this.sket.request.connection.remoteAddress;
            this.in = new BufferedInputStream(this.sket.getInputStream());
            byte[] dataAsByte = new byte[20]; in .read(dataAsByte);
            String msg = cript.decriptografa(dataAsByte);
            //in.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {}
        return msg;
    }


    public void desconectar() {
        try {
            this.sket.close();
            this.in.close();
            this.out.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (this.escutando) {
            try {
                this.msg = this.escutar();
                try {
                    this.callback();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Comunicador.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Comunicador.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

    public void callback() throws Exception {
        //System.out.println(msg);
        Servidor servidor = new Servidor();
        this.msg = servidor.tomadaDeAcao(this.msg);
        this.falar(this.msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Essa classe me parece bem estranha, em especial devido ao fato do método `run` só ter um `if` dentro, que depois de finalizado, mata a thread correspondente. De que forma você utiliza ou espera utilizar essa classe?

Answer (score 0):

Um primeiro comentário é que a classe de criptografia deveria começar com "C" maiúsculo.

Sobre o código apresentado tem algumas coisas a serem consideradas:

1. O ideal é ter uma classe para o servidor e outra para o cliente, isso porque o servidor precisa executar o accept no Socket (como tem no seu método iniciarServidor)
2. É muito estranho no seu método callback você criar um servidor novo para cada ação nova que é enviada. Isso vai criar vários objetos em memória e acredito que não seja esse o objetivo.
3. Embora você esteja separando cliente e servidor via sobrecarga de construtor isso é totalmente ilegível.

Ao que parece toda vez que uma ação é executada no servidor para um cliente que foi conectado ele abre um novo objeto servidor (que não está conectado naquele cliente) e isso poderia gerar essa visão de sistema congelado.